# Does this matrix have any properties?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The matrix is:
$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\sin{\theta}  & \cos{\theta} \\
\cos{\theta}  & \sin{\theta} \\
\end{array} \right) $

I'm interested in its effect on points in the first quadrant, but I haven't succeeded in finding anything unusual or interesting about it.